# catkin_make issue updating .srv and .cpp file simultaneously

Tags: c++, rosnode, ros-kinetic, rosservice, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Think of a situation where rosnode (written in c++) is using messages generated by a .srv file. You want to add a field to the .srv file and use it in the rosnode. If you make these changes simultaneously, catkin_make will fail because it does not yet recognize the new field you have added. Is there a way to make sure that message_generation occurs before compilation of c++ files during catkin_make? Would this even avoid the issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314050/catkin_make-issue-updating-.srv-and-.cpp-file-simultaneously/) by [stbuebel](https://answers.ros.org/users/39719/stbuebel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [catkin message documentation](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_msgs.html) describes how to do this. You can have messages in the same package as your executable, or in another package. In either case, if you're building with catkin_make, you need to tell cmake about the dependency between your C++ code and the messages.

If your messages are in the same package, you can use:

```
add_dependencies(your_program ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

If you use messages from a different package, you can use:

```
add_dependencies(your_program ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

If you use messages from other packages and your package, you will need both of those.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-29**:
+1 and I would add: storing msg/srv/action definitions in a separate package is almost always preferable over merging them into the pkg that hosts the node(s) using them.

It makes interfacing with your nodes much easier, as a "client" now only needs to build your msg pkg.